# Install and display SharePoint Hosted App(*.app) avoid manually "Trust In" to set the permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-hosted-app

For a requirement using SharePoint Online(Developer Tenant) regarding Site Provisioning, we need to install a SharePoint Hosted App(*.app) in the newly created sites. Doing this, the app is installing in the sites, but the user has to manually "Trust In" to set the permissions to get displayed on the site. Below screenshot for reference. **We need to automate this configuration. When a site is created/provisioned the app has to be displayed without any configurations. 
Kindly provide us with a solution for this.**

[image]

Comment: HI, There is a provision to do in App catalog site. You have deploy option so that it deploys to all sites and newly created site also. it is nothing but app stapling.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the the following articles for reference:

SharePoint 2013 App Deployment through "App Stapling"

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2013/03/04/sharepoint-2013-app-deployment-through-app-stapling/

Automating add-in/app installation to SharePoint sites using CSOM

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vesku/2015/11/20/automating-add-inapp-installation-to-sharepoint-sites-using-csom/

Comment: hi Suresh, we did tried the App Stapling method and using this will add the app in the site but need to manually install and "trust it" the app to get displayed on site. Our requirements is to add the app programmatically and yes we did tried and using CSOM, this installs the app, but the user needs to manually "trust it" the app to get displayed.